# How do you make a groovy tee?

Tags: groovy

I like to execute a command and copy its stdout and stderr to a logfile.

I like to run:

```
p = myexecute("ls -l /tmp/")
```

And essentially have the same Process object returned as:

```
p = "ls -l /tmp/".execute()
```

With the difference that stdout/stderr is copied to said logfile. I'm sure there is a simple way of doing this in groovy, but I'm not groovy enough yet to see it.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is long overdue, but one solution could be:

```
import groovy.ui.SystemOutputInterceptor

File logFile = new File('stdout.log')                                                                                
new SystemOutputInterceptor({logFile << it; true}).start() 
...
```

Comment: As of Groovy 2.4.6, the [callback takes 2 parameters](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.6/html/api/groovy/ui/SystemOutputInterceptor.html#SystemOutputInterceptor(groovy.lang.Closure)), so: new SystemOutputInterceptor({id, text -> logFile << text ; true} (Also, "true" means "also output to STDOUT")

Answer (score 1):

A better solution might be:

```
def logFile = new File( '/tmp/log.txt' )
logFile.withWriter('UTF-8') { sout ->
    p = "ls -l /tmp/".execute()
    p.waitForProcessOutput(sout, sout)
}
```

As this will wait for the process to complete

Comment: Of course, this in addition to something like [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) from apache commons might be more the complete solution you're probably after...

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's simple:

```
logFile.withWriter('UTF-8') { sout ->
    p = "ls -l /tmp/".execute()
    p.consumeProcessOutput(sout, sout)
}
```

This will write both streams to the same file.

For more examples, see http://groovy.codehaus.org/Process+Management

Comment: Ah, that's cool! But not what I want, sorry if I was unclear in my question. I like to "listen in" on the streams and copy them to a file without consuming them, a bit like the unix command [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) does.

Comment: That's simple: Implement your own `FilterWriter` and wrap `sout` with it.